# Polars - Get specific columns groupby column names based on expression

Tags: python, python-polars

I have a df as:

```
position    1164_1164.0 1164_1164.1 yes_001.0   yes_001.1   10316.0 10316.1 10349.0 10349.1 10418.0 10418.1
4414    0   1   0   0   1   0   0   0   1   1
5295    0   1   0   0   1   0   0   0   1   1
5738    0   1   0   0   1   0   0   0   1   1
5785    0   1   0   0   1   0   0   0   1   1
6392    0   1   0   0   1   0   0   0   1   1
7727    1   1   0   0   1   0   0   0   1   1
8876    1   1   0   0   1   0   0   0   1   1
9018    1   1   0   0   1   0   0   0   1   1
9208    1   1   0   0   1   0   1   0   1   1
9627    1   1   0   0   1   0   1   0   1   0
```

As you can see from the second column we have pairs of columns names separated by the suffixes .0 and .1

In pandas I am able to groupby excluding the first column, the columns by an expression that would capture the column names before "." in the column names as follow:

```
g = df.iloc[:,1:].groupby(df.columns[1:].str.extract(r'(\w+)\.', expand=False), axis=1)
```

I am trying to do the same with Polars but all I could get is this far:

```
g = df[:,1:].groupby(df.columns[1:])
```

Now, I tried the `str.extract(r'(\w+)\.'` but it gives an error as:

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'str'
```

EDIT:

I was able to come up with this but It is still giving me an error when I try some calculations:

```
g = df[:,1:].groupby(pl.col("*").str.extract(r'(\w+)\.'))
```

Then when I try:

```
s = g.sum()
```

I get:

```
DuplicateError: column with name '1164_1164.0' has more than one occurrences
```

Answer (score 0):

It helps if you provide an example in code.

The first point to note is:

- `df.columns` is not special in polars - it's just a python list.

The main problem is that the shape of your data does not suit polars.

The reason for this is that polars works with types:

- a column has a single type - which is guaranteed
- going "sideways" introduces multiple possible types

You can reshape your data into single columns using [`.melt`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/dataframe/api/polars.DataFrame.melt.html#polars.DataFrame.melt)

```
(df
 .with_row_count()
 .melt(id_vars=("row_nr", "position"), variable_name="column")
 .with_columns(prefix = pl.col("column").str.replace(r"[.][^.]+$", "")))
```

```
shape: (20, 5)
┌────────┬──────────┬─────────────┬───────┬───────────┐
│ row_nr | position | column      | value | prefix    │
│ ---    | ---      | ---         | ---   | ---       │
│ u32    | i64      | str         | i64   | str       │
╞════════╪══════════╪═════════════╪═══════╪═══════════╡
│ 0      | 1        | 1164_1164.0 | 1     | 1164_1164 │
│ 1      | 2        | 1164_1164.0 | 2     | 1164_1164 │
│ 0      | 1        | 1164_1164.1 | 1     | 1164_1164 │
│ 1      | 2        | 1164_1164.1 | 2     | 1164_1164 │
│ ...    | ...      | ...         | ...   | ...       │
│ 0      | 1        | 10418.0     | 1     | 10418     │
│ 1      | 2        | 10418.0     | 2     | 10418     │
│ 0      | 1        | 10418.1     | 1     | 10418     │
│ 1      | 2        | 10418.1     | 2     | 10418     │
└────────┴──────────┴─────────────┴───────┴───────────┘
```

You can then `.groupby`

```
(df
 .with_row_count().melt(id_vars=("row_nr", "position"), variable_name="column")
 .with_columns(prefix = pl.col("column").str.replace(r"[.][^.]+$", ""))
 .groupby("row_nr", "prefix")
 .agg(
    pl.col("column"), 
    pl.first("position"), 
    pl.col("value").sum())
)
```

```
shape: (10, 5)
┌────────┬───────────┬────────────────────────────────┬──────────┬───────┐
│ row_nr | prefix    | column                         | position | value │
│ ---    | ---       | ---                            | ---      | ---   │
│ u32    | str       | list[str]                      | i64      | i64   │
╞════════╪═══════════╪════════════════════════════════╪══════════╪═══════╡
│ 1      | 10349     | ["10349.0", "10349.1"]         | 2        | 4     │
│ 0      | 10349     | ["10349.0", "10349.1"]         | 1        | 2     │
│ 0      | 10418     | ["10418.0", "10418.1"]         | 1        | 2     │
│ 0      | yes_001   | ["yes_001.0", "yes_001.1"]     | 1        | 2     │
│ ...    | ...       | ...                            | ...      | ...   │
│ 0      | 1164_1164 | ["1164_1164.0", "1164_1164.1"] | 1        | 2     │
│ 1      | yes_001   | ["yes_001.0", "yes_001.1"]     | 2        | 4     │
│ 1      | 10316     | ["10316.0", "10316.1"]         | 2        | 4     │
│ 1      | 10418     | ["10418.0", "10418.1"]         | 2        | 4     │
└────────┴───────────┴────────────────────────────────┴──────────┴───────┘
```

To go from *"long to wide"* - you can [`.pivot`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/dataframe/api/polars.DataFrame.pivot.html#polars.DataFrame.pivot)

```
(df
 .with_row_count().melt(id_vars=("row_nr", "position"), variable_name="column")
 .with_columns(prefix = pl.col("column").str.replace(r"[.][^.]+$", ""))
 .groupby("row_nr", "prefix", maintain_order=True)
 .agg(
    pl.col("column"), 
    pl.first("position"), 
    pl.col("value").sum())
 .explode(pl.col("column"))
 .pivot(
   index=("row_nr", "position"), 
   columns="column", 
   values="value")
)
```

```
shape: (2, 12)
┌────────┬──────────┬─────────────┬─────────────┬─────┬─────────┬─────────┬─────────┬─────────┐
│ row_nr | position | 1164_1164.0 | 1164_1164.1 | ... | 10349.0 | 10349.1 | 10418.0 | 10418.1 │
│ ---    | ---      | ---         | ---         |     | ---     | ---     | ---     | ---     │
│ u32    | i64      | i64         | i64         |     | i64     | i64     | i64     | i64     │
╞════════╪══════════╪═════════════╪═════════════╪═════╪═════════╪═════════╪═════════╪═════════╡
│ 0      | 1        | 2           | 2           | ... | 2       | 2       | 2       | 2       │
│ 1      | 2        | 4           | 4           | ... | 4       | 4       | 4       | 4       │
└────────┴──────────┴─────────────┴─────────────┴─────┴─────────┴─────────┴─────────┴─────────┘
```

<sup>`maintain_order=True` was added to the `.groupby` to keep the row order</sup>

---

dataframe used:

```
schema = ["position"] + """
1164_1164.0 1164_1164.1 yes_001.0   yes_001.1   
10316.0 10316.1 10349.0 10349.1 10418.0 10418.1
""".split()

df = pl.DataFrame([[1] * len(schema)] + [[2] * len(schema)], schema=schema)
```

```
shape: (2, 11)
┌──────────┬─────────────┬─────────────┬───────────┬─────┬─────────┬─────────┬─────────┬─────────┐
│ position | 1164_1164.0 | 1164_1164.1 | yes_001.0 | ... | 10349.0 | 10349.1 | 10418.0 | 10418.1 │
│ ---      | ---         | ---         | ---       |     | ---     | ---     | ---     | ---     │
│ i64      | i64         | i64         | i64       |     | i64     | i64     | i64     | i64     │
╞══════════╪═════════════╪═════════════╪═══════════╪═════╪═════════╪═════════╪═════════╪═════════╡
│ 1        | 1           | 1           | 1         | ... | 1       | 1       | 1       | 1       │
│ 2        | 2           | 2           | 2         | ... | 2       | 2       | 2       | 2       │
└──────────┴─────────────┴─────────────┴───────────┴─────┴─────────┴─────────┴─────────┴─────────┘
```